# rosmsg show in C++

Tags: c++, roscpp, rostopic, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'd like a way I can recursively iterate all topics/types in C++.  Essentially a rosmsg show through all types, down to the basic types.  I've seen it done in Python using the function get_topic_class() but I have thoroughly searched and been unable to find a way to do this in C++.  Anyone have any ideas?  I really don't want to have to hard code all of my message types (we have about thirty custom message types).  Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57915/rosmsg-show-in-c++/) by [Chuck Claunch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3719/chuck-claunch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 206 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What do you mean with hard code? Do you want to be able to pass in a type as a string definition like "geometry_msgs/PoseStamped" without have that type in your code?
That is likely to be impossible as c++ needs to know about the type.

If you just want to access a specific known (at compile-time) type in general, generated messages provide a specialization of the Definition struct with a value() function that contains the message definition.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chuck Claunch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3719/chuck-claunch/) on 2013-03-12**:
I don't necessarily need to have the ability to process the type without including the headers, I understand that.  I simply want to be able to recursively run down the full list of topics and drill down to the most basic data types available (as strings).  (the exact funcationality of rosmsg show).

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-12**:
I see what you mean. My guess is: impossible, but maybe someone can come up with a solution to that.

**Comment by [Chuck Claunch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3719/chuck-claunch/) on 2013-03-12**:
Well it'd be possible with system execs but that's a really hokey solution.  I'd hope if we can do this in Python it could be done in C++.  Thanks for the effort, the "impossible" is what brings me here :)